# Why do 2D graphics systems use a move to, line to style interface?

Tags: 2d, line, vector-graphics

I've noticed most primitive drawing libraries (GDI, HTML5 canvas) use a procedural from where sequence matters with operations like: move_to and line_to and set_stroke etc...

Why use sequence dependant operations like move_to, line_to instead of something like: line(start, end)?

Answer (score 0):

Most things that people want to draw consist of connected strokes. The start of stroke N+1 is nearly always the end of stroke N. So it makes sense for the drawing system to store a current point as part of its state, and use that as the start of each operation, with a move_to command to start at a new position without drawing anything.

Comment: There's got to be a better reason. People do not use these libraries directly very much, most it is some algorithm that needs to draw, for instance, a box with height and width and an origin.